# Flatbuffer serialization performance is slow compared to protobuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, flatbuffers

With following IDL files my intention is to measure the serialization speed of Flatbuffer . I am using golang for my analysis

```
namespace MyFlat;

struct Vertices {
    x : double;
    y  :double;

}
table Polygon  {

    polygons : [Vertices];
}

table Layer {

    polygons : [Polygon];
}
root_type Layer;
```

Here is the code I have written for calculation

package main

```
import (
    "MyFlat"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    flatbuffers "github.com/google/flatbuffers/go"
)

func calculation(size int, vertices int) {
    b := flatbuffers.NewBuilder(0)
    var polyoffset []flatbuffers.UOffsetT

    rawSize := ((16 * vertices) * size) / 1024
    var vec1 flatbuffers.UOffsetT
    var StartedAtMarshal time.Time
    var EndedAtMarshal time.Time
    StartedAtMarshal = time.Now()
    for k := 0; k < size; k++ {

        MyFlat.PolygonStartPolygonsVector(b, vertices)

        for i := 0; i < vertices; i++ {
            MyFlat.CreateVertices(b, 2.0, 2.4)

        }

        vec1 = b.EndVector(vertices)
        MyFlat.PolygonStart(b)
        MyFlat.PolygonAddPolygons(b, vec1)
        polyoffset = append(polyoffset, MyFlat.PolygonEnd(b))

    }

    MyFlat.LayerStartPolygonsVector(b, size)
    for _, offset := range polyoffset {
        b.PrependUOffsetT(offset)
    }
    vec := b.EndVector(size)
    MyFlat.LayerStart(b)
    MyFlat.LayerAddPolygons(b, vec)
    finalOffset := MyFlat.LayerEnd(b)

    b.Finish(finalOffset)
    EndedAtMarshal = time.Now()

    SeElaprseTime := EndedAtMarshal.Sub(StartedAtMarshal).String()
    mybyte := b.FinishedBytes()
    file := "/tmp/myflat_" + strconv.Itoa(size) + ".txt"
    if err := ioutil.WriteFile(file, mybyte, 0644); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to write address book:", err)
    }

    StartedAt := time.Now()

    layer := MyFlat.GetRootAsLayer(mybyte, 0)

    size = layer.PolygonsLength()
    obj := &MyFlat.Polygon{}
    layer.Polygons(obj, 1)

    for i := 0; i < obj.PolygonsLength(); i++ {
        objVertices := &MyFlat.Vertices{}
        obj.Polygons(objVertices, i)
        fmt.Println(objVertices.X(), objVertices.Y())
    }

    EndedAt := time.Now()
    DeElapseTime := EndedAt.Sub(StartedAt).String()
    fmt.Println(size, ",", vertices, ", ", SeElaprseTime, ",", DeElapseTime, ",", (len(mybyte) / 1024), ",", rawSize)
}

func main() {

    data := []int{500000, 1000000, 1500000, 3000000, 8000000}

    for _, size := range data {
        //calculation(size, 5)
        //calculation(size, 10)
        calculation(size, 20)

    }
}
```

Problem is I find it serialization is quite slow compared to protobuff  with similar idl.

For 3M polygons serialization its taking almost 4.1167037s. Where in protobuf its taking half. Deserilization time for flatbuf is very less (in micro sec). In protobuf its quite high. But still if I add both flatbuf performance is lower.

Do you see any optimized way to serialize it. Flatbuffer is having a method createBinaryVector for byte vector but there is no direct way to serialize  vector of polygon from a existing a user defined type vector.

I am adding protobuf code also

syntax = 'proto3';

```
package myproto; 
message Polygon {
                 repeated double v_x = 1 ;
                 repeated  double v_y = 2 ;
            }
message CADData {


       repeated Polygon polygon = 1;
        string layer_name = 2;
}
```

Go Code with protobuf

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "myproto"
    "strconv"
    "time"

    "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"
)

func calculation(size int, vertices int) {
    var comp []*myproto.Polygon
    var vx []float64
    var vy []float64
    for i := 0; i < vertices; i++ {
        r := 0 + rand.Float64()*(10-0)
        vx = append(vx, r)
        vy = append(vy, r/2)

    }
    rawSize := ((16 * vertices) * size) / 1024
    StartedAtMarshal := time.Now()

    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        comp = append(comp, &myproto.Polygon{

            VX: vx,
            VY: vy,
        })
    }
    pfs := &myproto.CADData{
        LayerName: "Layer",
        Polygon:   comp,
    }
    data, err := proto.Marshal(pfs)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("marshaling error: ", err)
    }
    EndedAtMarshal := time.Now()
    SeElaprseTime := EndedAtMarshal.Sub(StartedAtMarshal).String()
    file := "/tmp/myproto_" + strconv.Itoa(size) + ".txt"
    if err := ioutil.WriteFile(file, data, 0644); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to write address book:", err)
    }

    StartedAt := time.Now()

    serialized := &myproto.CADData{}
    proto.Unmarshal(data, serialized)
    EndedAt := time.Now()
    DeElapseTime := EndedAt.Sub(StartedAt).String()
    fmt.Println(size, ",", vertices, ", ", SeElaprseTime, ",", DeElapseTime, ",", (len(data) / 1024), ",", rawSize)
}

func main() {
    data := []int{500000, 1000000, 1500000, 3000000, 8000000}
    for _, size := range data {
        //  calculation(size, 5)
        //calculation(size, 10)
        calculation(size, 20)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The time you give, is that for serialization, de-serialization, or both?

Your de-serialization code is likely entirely dominated by `fmt.Println`. Why don't you instead do `sum += objVertices.X() + objVertices.Y()` and print `sum` after timing is done? Can you pull `objVertices := &MyFlat.Vertices{}` outside of the loop?

You didn't post your protobuf code. Are you including in the timing the time to create the tree of objects which is being serialized (which is required for use in Protobuf but not in FlatBuffers)? Similarly, are you doing the timed (de-)serialization at least a 1000x or so, so you can include the cost of GC (Protobuf allocates a LOT of objects, FlatBuffers allocates few/none) in your comparison?

If after you do the above, it is still slower, post on the FlatBuffers github issues, the authors of the Go port may be able to help further. Make sure you post full code for both systems, and full timings.

Note generally: the design of FlatBuffers is such that it will create the biggest performance gap with Protobuf in C/C++. That said, it should still be a lot faster in Go also. There are unfortunate things about Go however that prevent it from maximizing the performance potential.

Comment: I have updated the question by adding protobuf code. And to your answer the time I mentioned is only serialization time. De-Ser is quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
    b := flatbuffers.NewBuilder(0)
```

I'm not sure what the "grows automatically" behavior is in Go for flatbuffers, but I'm pretty sure requiring the buffer to grow automatically is not the *preferred* pattern. Could you try doing your same timing comparison after initializing the buffer with `flatbuffers.NewBuilder(moreBytesThanTheMessageNeeds)`?